# meditation on the heartbeat

Tags: meditation-recommendation, meditation-body

Usually we use an anchor in meditation, the breathing being the most common. Sometimes when I focus on that I feel my heartbeat taking my attention, so I thought about using that as an anchor, does anyone know if there is a meditation technique that uses the heartbeat?

PS: I'm aware this does not apply to all types of meditation

Answer (score 2):

You can use it if it serves you the purpose of one-pointedness attention.
But you should remember the benefits of using the breath as your point of attention.
The breath is both a concious and unconcious function and because of that it serves as a bridge bwtween them.
Also in Tibetan Buddhism conciouness is said to "ride" in the winds (prana) of the body so by focusing in the breath you are also focusing in your mind.
Once you have achieved mindfulness thru the attention to your heart beat, it is better to switch to your breath.

Answer (score 0):

My unorthodox answer is that empirically, have you ever heard someone say that heartbeat meditation really helped them? Did it help them know themselves or become enlightened? In browsing around meditation forums and message boards, I've literally never seen a recommendation for this. I infer that statistically, it's not likely to be the most profound type of meditation.

Can you try it? Why not!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same experience.
It is better to ignore the heartbeat and focus on the breath for countless reasons!
Calmer mind, more stable heartrate, blissful, easier, wind element cultivation... the reasons are endless.

There are no good reasons to meditate on the heartbeat except until you have attained the 3rd jhana at least, after which you can practice extreme ascetic practices.

But you asked for how to meditate on the heartbeat:
all meditation methods are the same, notice the in and out.
Gradually you will notice the space between the in and out.
Include this space in your observation: in, space, out, space, in, space, out, etc.

Gradually this space will open up and you can enter jhana.

For more info on meditation and how it works read [this](http://www.meditationexpert.com/ebok/howtomeditate.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main bodily functions. The breath and the heartbeat.

In calming the bodily fabrications it is not just calming the breath until it stops. When the breath stops then you have to look at any movement on the body. Generally it will be the heartbeat. This will also eventually slowdown and stop. This is the point where you have calmed down all bodily fabrications. (In context of Anapana you have completed the 1st 4 stages.)